# PowerShell and .NET

Tags: vb.net, powershell, powershell-3.0

I've searched around for a solution for the problem I am facing when trying to run PowerShell from VB.net. I'm not very experienced in coding so excuse if I don't use the proper terminology.

Below I have copied the code that I am working with. When I compile the code and execute the program I get a few exceptions that Point to PowerShell modules missing. I have done a lot of searching around to make sure I am not missing the required PowerShell modules and / or assemblies.

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Management.Automation
Imports System.Management.Automation.Runspaces
Imports System.Management.Automation.Host
Imports System.Text
Public Class Form1
Private Function RunScript(ByVal Script As String) As Object
    Dim MyRunSpace As Runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()
    MyRunSpace.Open()
    Dim MyPipeline As Pipeline = MyRunSpace.CreatePipeline()
    MyPipeline.Commands.AddScript(Script)
    Dim results As Collection(Of PSObject) = MyPipeline.Invoke()
    MyRunSpace.Close()
    Dim MyStringBuilder As New StringBuilder()
    For Each obj As PSObject In results
        MyStringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString())
    Next
    Return MyStringBuilder
End Function
Private Function GetAD()
    Dim Script As New StringBuilder()
    Script.Append("$ADUSER= Get-ADUser -filter { cn -eq " + Chr(34) + "Common Name" + Chr(34) + " }" + vbCrLf)
    Script.Append("$ADUSER" + vbCrLf)
    Return Script.ToString()
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Call RunScript(GetAD)
End Sub


Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged
    RichTextBox1.Text = ToString()
End Sub
End Class
```

Here are the Exceptions that the Compiler Returns when the PowerShell pipeline processes the Script and returns it back to compiler. Again I have made sure that I have the RSAT installed on my computer. Also made sure that I had some old NET 3.5 SDK. All of the search results on this particular issue have not been helpful so far.

```
+       Exception   Exception thrown: 'System.DllNotFoundException' in System.Management.Automation.dll ("Unable to load DLL 'wldp.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)")    System.DllNotFoundException

Exception thrown: 'System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException' in System.Management.Automation.dll ("Cannot find path 'C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\ActiveDirectory\Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management' because it does not exist.")

Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll ("Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.")

Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll ("Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\ActiveDirectory\Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.")

Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll ("Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.")

Exception thrown: 'System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException' in System.Management.Automation.dll ("The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management' is not installed on this computer.")
```

Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your exception #2 clearly states that the path given does not exist, you should check that first, and I belive its the seme issue for the others.

Comment: I've checked the referenced path on the exception and the directory is there and there are files within, although I am not sure if there are missing files within the referenced directory.

Comment: If you're in a 32-bit VB.NET app, you will need to look in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules

Comment: I've checked both paths, all of the powershell modules seem to be there. I am stumped at this point. I also installed Windows Management Frameworks 3.0 and currently installing Management Frameworks 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue today. I figured out what my issue was and may be yours as well. I'm not that great at programming either.

This

`Script.Append("$ADUSER" + vbCrLf)` should be `Script.Append("$ADUSER.Name" + vbCrLf)`

Once you add the `.Name` to the command, will output it without any issues.